# hreflang on non-duplicate website

Tags: internationalization, seo, sitemap

Looking to utilize hreflang on multilanguage website.  Here's the scenario:

Initially there were 3 versions (out of date, non-SEO compliant, Flash included) of the same website. English, Korean, Chinese.  We updated the English version to a brand new (SEO friendly) website, while leaving the Korean & Chinese version the same.

I've employed the following code in both the sitemap & on the headers of the non-English versions:

Sitemap:

```
<url>
    <loc>http://example.com</loc>
    <xhtml:link
        rel="alternate"
        hreflang="zh"
        href="http://example.com/cn"
        />
    <xhtml:link
        rel="alternate"
        hreflang="ko"
        href="http://example.com/kr"
        />
</url>
```

The header for the non-English versions:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="zh-us" href="http://example.com/cn"/>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="ko-us" href="http://example.com/kr"/>
```

Do I need to add the hreflang tag to the new updated English version as well?  Is there anything else I need to add to the international versions?

Many thanks in advance for assistance!

Comment: "Do I need to add the hreflang tag to the new updated English version as well?" --- "need" according to …?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this code in both sitemap and header. Use it only in one place. I recommend you to remove it from the sitemap.

Also, you need to have the links to all the language versions on all pages in different language. For example, you should put:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://example.com/en" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="ko-us" href="http://example.com/kr" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="zh-us" href="http://example.com/cn" />
```

Or, even better, you can make English default:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="http://example.com/en" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="ko-us" href="http://example.com/kr" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="zh-us" href="http://example.com/cn" />
```

For reference, check this link: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en